# PHP Save text after submit

Tags: php

Trying to keep my text saved in my form after on-click submit.
It works without saving the text.

```
$reqmethod=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
$isPost=False;
if( $reqmethod == "POST") {
   $id = $_POST["Id"];
   $isPost = True;
```

this is in a different page than the actual form

```
<form method="POST">
<?php (isset($show_form) { ?>
    Id: <input type='Text' name='Id' value='<?=$id?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type='Submit' name='Search' value='Search'>
<?php {
?>
</form>
```

I tried changing my form line to this, but nothing on my webpage showed, just a blank white screen:

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" name="myForm" id="idForm">
```

Looked at this link for reference, but can't figure this out.
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/564843-how-to-keep-input-fields-after-page-refresh/

Comment: `id = $_POST["Id"];` missing $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

Comment: You stated "this is in a different page than the actual form", maybe it means that $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is not getting POSTed?

Comment: Are the two blocks of code above in the same file or in different files?

Comment: @csb different files

Comment: So then unless you're doing some `include` or passing your variables through `$_SESSION`, the file with your HTML code will not be able to read the value of `$show_form` and `$id`, which was set in the other file.

Comment: if your php code is in different page then you have to set session or you can place php code in form page to get result.